# How to retrieve rows with XML column that have specific child node?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server with an XML column:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.XmlData (
    id INT IDENTITY,
    data XML
);
```

The XML stored in the `data` column is dynamic, I mean, only some of them have certain child node. Additionally, this nodes appear in different locations within the XML structure.

Example 1, `/RootNode/FindMe`**:**

```
<RootNode>
    <ChildNodeOne>One</ChildNodeOne>
    <ChildNodeTwo>Two</ChildNodeTwo>
    <ChildNodeThree>Three</ChildNodeThree>
    <FindMe>FindMe</FindMe>
</RootNode>
```

Example 2, `/RootNode/ChildNodeThree/Deeper/FindMe` and `/RootNode/ChildNodeTwo/FindMe` **:**

```
<RootNode>
    <ChildNodeOne>One</ChildNodeOne>
    <ChildNodeTwo>
        <FindMe>FindMe</FindMe>
    </ChildNodeTwo>
    <ChildNodeThree>
        <Deeper>
            <FindMe>FindMe</FindMe>
        </Deeper>
    </ChildNodeThree>
</RootNode>
```

There are rows with the XML column that doesn't have the `<FindMe/>` node.

I need to write a query to retrieve only the rows that have the `<FindMe/>` node. No matter its location within the XML structure.

Comment: Use `//FindMe` instead

Comment: It worked! You can add additional details below and I'll accept your answer. Thanks @MatthewWhited

Comment: your problem was with XPath not SQL.  and I'm too lazy to write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to know is, that `//FindMe` will trigger a **deep search**. That means: *Find this node whereever it exists in the XML*. A single `/` marks the root element (*Start the search at the beginning*) and `no slash at all` marks the current node (*Continue from the context node*):

In the following there are some examples how one could query for a node name:

A dummy table for tests:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DummyTbl (
    id INT IDENTITY,
    Remark VARCHAR(100),
    data XML
);

INSERT INTO DummyTbl VALUES
('FindMe is on second level',
'<RootNode>
    <ChildNodeOne>One</ChildNodeOne>
    <ChildNodeTwo>Two</ChildNodeTwo>
    <ChildNodeThree>Three</ChildNodeThree>
    <FindMe>FindMe 1</FindMe>
</RootNode>')
,('FindMe is two times somewhere deeper',
'<RootNode>
    <ChildNodeOne>One</ChildNodeOne>
    <ChildNodeTwo>
        <FindMe>FindMe 2a</FindMe>
    </ChildNodeTwo>
    <ChildNodeThree>
        <Deeper>
            <FindMe>FindMe 2b</FindMe>
        </Deeper>
    </ChildNodeThree>
</RootNode>')
,('FindMe does not exist',
'<RootNode>
    <ChildNodeOne>One</ChildNodeOne>
    <ChildNodeTwo>
    </ChildNodeTwo>
    <ChildNodeThree>
        <Deeper>
            <FindMeNot>Something else</FindMeNot>
        </Deeper>
    </ChildNodeThree>
</RootNode>')
,('FindMe exists, but is empty',
'<RootNode>
    <ChildNodeOne>One</ChildNodeOne>
    <ChildNodeTwo>
    </ChildNodeTwo>
    <ChildNodeThree>
        <Deeper>
            <FindMe/>
        </Deeper>
    </ChildNodeThree>
</RootNode>');
```

Different queries:

--All FindMe nodes (inlcuding the empty one)

```
SELECT d.id,d.Remark
      ,f.value('.','nvarchar(max)') FindMeNode
FROM dbo.DummyTbl AS d
CROSS APPLY d.data.nodes('//FindMe') AS A(f)
```

--All IDs where there is at least one "FindMe"-node

```
SELECT d.id,d.Remark
FROM dbo.DummyTbl AS d
WHERE d.data.exist('//FindMe')=1
GO
```

--All IDs where there is at least one "FindMe"-node, but not the empty one

```
SELECT d.id,d.Remark
FROM dbo.DummyTbl AS d
WHERE d.data.exist('//FindMe/text()')=1
```

--Find IDs, where there is at least one empty FindMe node

```
SELECT d.id,d.Remark
FROM dbo.DummyTbl AS d
WHERE d.data.exist('//FindMe[empty(text())]')=1
```

--Now with a variable name to search for

```
DECLARE @SearchForName NVARCHAR(100)='FindMe'; 
SELECT d.id,d.Remark
FROM dbo.DummyTbl AS d
WHERE d.data.exist('//*[local-name()=sql:variable("@SearchForName")]/text()')=1
GO
```

--Clean up

```
DROP TABLE dbo.DummyTbl;
```

Comment: Always impressed with your COMPREHENSIVE answers.  This deserves +1 for each of the 5 snippets